# My custom function in PowerShell isn't working the way I expect it to

Tags: powershell

```
function CopyFiles($source, $destination)
{
    Write-Host "Source is " $source
    Write-Host "Destination is " $destination
    Copy-Item -Force -Recurse –Verbose $source -Destination $destination
}
```

When debugging, my source looks like it's combining the source and destination into a single string. is  C:\shortcuts* \Server\Folder\User\person\Desktop

And destination looks empty

I am making a function call from my code that looks like

```
CopyFiles $source, $serverPath
```

Can anyone please explain what I am doing wrong or how I can fix it?

Answer (score 3):

You firstly have your string quoting wrong. It should be:

```
function CopyFiles($source, $destination)
{
    Write-Host "Source is $source"
    Write-Host "Destination is $destination"
    Copy-Item -Force -Recurse –Verbose $source -Destination $destination
}
```

Secondly, you're calling the function incorrectly. It should be

```
CopyFiles $source $serverPath
```

The way you're doing it, you actually pass the `$source` function argument as a string array. That's why you see them printed together and the destination as empty, you're not actually passing the `$destination` argument